# Warning developers about out of date dependencies

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, hudson, build-process

Is there a way in Maven, Hudson, or Sonar to *warn* on the inclusion of *certain* out of date artifacts in a build.

For example, consider having a number of internal business jars. Some versions of these jars can go through an end-of-life phase. During this time, it would be nice if any builds that occurred would issue some sort warning and direct the user to some documentation about the issue.

To be clear, builds shouldn't fail. Also, we only want to apply this logic to a certain set of artifacts, not everything.

Comment: Just a vague idea - if you moved the out-of-date artifacts to a different repository, maybe there's some way you can bring up a warning whenever that repository is tapped?

Comment: @AndrewSpencer: do you know of a practical way of doing that? I do not.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer I'd consider that a bad idea. Moving or removing artefacts would break builds using them. I think the objective here is generate build-time warnings

Comment: Even if it didn't break things, most of the time the old libraries would already be in `~/.m2/repository` and the remote ones wouldn't get touched.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor You'd have both repositories in your settings so it wouldn't break anything.

Comment: @Inerdial True but you should be building from a clean local repo for anything more important than personal developer builds.

Comment: @AndrewWhite Not off the top of my head, and I'm not free to research the question just now. And on reflection, something about this idea doesn't quite _feel_ right (despite my just having defended it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the [enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) to specify the dependencies which are no longer allowed.

Plugin has goals to either enforce the rules (thereby failing your build) or print a violation report.

## Update

I use the dependencies report in [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) to lookup cross project usage of obsolete libraries.
I know you're also using Sonar, but just in case here's an example:

- Usage of [log4j, version 1.2.9](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/dependencies?resource=log4j%3alog4j&search=log4j&version=1.2.9).

(This information is coming from the Maven POM of each project analysed by Sonar).

I think what you're really looking for, does not currently exist.... A plugin that works like the standard Maven enforcer plugin, but is configured from and raises violations in Sonar!

Why don't you post this as an idea on the Sonar JIRA?

Comment: Now this is looking promising. I just need to find a way to ensure the list of excludes is maintained. Perhaps keeping a list in the super pom on the Hudson server. Do you have any advice on ensuring the enforcement and upkeep of the enforcer?

Comment: Actually I don't use the enforcer plug-in to analyse dependencies. Instead I use Sonar (See update)

Comment: If you go with a greylist (I suppose that's the right term for something that generates warnings rather than failures), keeping it somewhere visible is important. I like the Sonar idea.

Comment: @AndrewSpencer "greylist" I like that! Good proposal for a plug-in name :-)

Answer (score 6):

Using the maven dependency plugin you can run this

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

This will display a list of all artifacts that have newer versions available in the repository.  Just have the devs run that every so often and update accordingly.

Comment: This is not enforceable as is and it is not limited to a certain subset of artifacts (both of which are important here). However, you have given me an idea around using this with a weekly-hudson job.

Comment: I can't find a way to limit which artifacts it checks. As an aside, tt also appears that the plugin is rather picky about version format; I notice that it thinks spring 2.5.6 is greater than 3.0.5.RELEASE. Having to create a version rules config seems daunting if we ever decided to use this in a more general way.

Comment: Yeah, the version strategy assumes that all versions are of the same pattern.  I have the case where a.b.c.d is greater than e.f but it thinks e.f is newer.  It's not ideal, but running that plugin through a shell script for some filtering is easy enough.  Not 100% what you want though.

Comment: +1 for an idea I had never heard of, even tho it didn't solve the op's question